# Dealing with 2D grids with MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I'm using MPI to parallelise some simple C code, but I'm having a hard time fundamentally understanding it.

Everything was quite reasonable when I was first learning about MPI, but this has stumped me. If you create a 2D grid using two nested loops, i.e.

```
for(i=0; i<imax; i++) { 
    for(j=0; j<jmax; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = ...
    }
}
```

How would you even go about parallelising this? I initially thought you would use a master thread to gather all of the data that each thread calculates, but apparently this scales badly.

I believe you need to call MPI_Gather(...) for all processes, but I don't really understand how you would then collect this data into one coherent 2D grid.

I should probably note that the ... in the loop is just where it calculates a small value for each grid point. It uses a red/black scheme, so there are no issues with race conditions, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you want to do with `grid` after you calculate it? Why do you need all the data in one process?